# unwanted '/' at the end of two concatenated strings used in <img/> tag

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple laravel project.I want to concatenate  two string.

```
$base_url ="https://image_base_url/";
$image_path = "/image_name.jpg";
$full_url=$base_url.$image_path;
```

then I use full_url inside img tag like so in laravel in index.blade.php file

```
<img src={{$full_url}} />;
```

> the full_url is correct but when it place in src it will get an '/' at
> the end of it and image can not find that url

**src will be like below**
src ="http://baseurl/imagepath.jpg/"

**but I want it like this**

```
src="http://baseurl/imagepath.jpg"
```

any of you my friends can help me out?thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do like this

```
<img src="{{$full_url}}" />;
```

Comment: thank you it worked.but do you have any idea why this extra '/' added to concatenated string in src attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write php variable in double quotes.

```
<img src="{{$full_url}}" alt="tag" />;
```

It's good practice to add `alt=""` attribute in `img` tag